# Ошибка "Unknown column"

Tags: mysql

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE user = `test2`
```

Где ошибка?
­
Ответ от запроса в phpmyadmin:

SQL-запрос:

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE user = `test2`
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Ответ MySQL:

> `#1054 - Unknown column 'test2' in 'where clause'`
>   ­
>   Вот таблица:

[image]
­
В чем причина то?

Comment: Название таблицы в phpmyadmin покажите.

Comment: Kite - Ваш совет помог! Напишите как ответ и я приму его.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Строки нужно брать в кавычки:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = "test2" LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: А поля и таблицы в апострофы.

Comment: Необязательно. Нужно только если имена объектов БД совпадают с [зарезервированными словами][1]

  [1]: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: @KiTE да-да.