# Ошибка в классе php

Tags: ооп, php, mysql

Есть класс работы с базой данных.

Ссылка: http://pastebin.com/en0svZkd

Так же есть класс для работы с пользователями, использующий в себе класс для работы с бд.

Ссылка: http://pastebin.com/6EZCcMTT

Но пользователи в БД не заносятся, подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: а что он говорит? есть какие-то ошибки от базы или от php?

Comment: не вставляет записи может из-за опечатки? $this->db->jqery(...); Вообще надо яснее писать ошибки какие возникают, что пишут, что происходит.

Comment: Добавил вывод ошибок при запросе к бд.
echo mysql_error();
Но в ответ тишина, все проверил, jqery заменил на query для понятности самого кода.

Comment: @lordonx3 поздравляю, вы слили в открытый доступ все данные, необходимые для подключения к вашей БД, упростив потенциальному злоумышленнику задачу вдвое. Постарайтесь больше так не делать.

Comment: @Fike, данные не валидные, перед постингом были изменены :)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка "Unknown column"](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/90301/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-unknown-column)